# PHP fails calling function

Tags: php, function

I have a problem calling php function when i click submit button:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['username']) === true and empty($_GET['username']) === false) {
$username       = $_GET['username'];

if(user_exists($username) === true) {
$profile_user_id        = user_id_from_username($username, 'username');
$my_id                  = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$profile_data           = user_data($profile_user_id, 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile');
?>

    <h1><?php echo $profile_data['first_name']; ?>'s Profile</h1>
    <?php
    if($profile_user_id != $my_id) {
        $check_friend_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM friends WHERE (user_one='$my_id' AND user_two='$profile_user_id') OR (user_one='$profile_user_id' AND user_two='$my_id')");
        if(mysql_num_rows($check_friend_query) > 0) {
            echo '<a href="">Already Friends </a>- <a href="">Unfriend '. $profile_data['username'] .'</a>';
        } else {
            $from_query = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM friend_request WHERE `from` = '$profile_user_id' AND `to` = '$my_id'");
            $to_query   = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM friend_request WHERE `from` = '$my_id' AND `to` = '$profile_user_id'");
            if(mysql_num_rows($from_query) == 1) {
                 echo '<a href="#">Ignore</a> or <a href="">Accept</a>';
            } elseif(mysql_num_rows($to_query) == 1){
                 echo '<a href="#">Cancel Request</a>';
            } else {
                 if(isset($_GET['submit'])) {
                    friend_request();
                    header('Location: '.$profile_user_id);
                    exit();
                 }
                    ?>
                        <form action="">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send friend request!">
                        </form>
                    <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

That last else isser($*GET['submit'] and function call with form.What is wrong* I cant find the solution,it just refreshes the page but doenst send mysql_query. Function that i call is this:

```
function friend_request() {
if (isset($_GET['username']) === true and empty($_GET['username']) === false) {
$username       = $_GET['username'];

    if(user_exists($username) === true) {
    $profile_user_id        = user_id_from_username($username, 'username');
    $my_id                  = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $profile_data           = user_data($profile_user_id, 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'profile');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO friend_request VALUES('', '$my_id', '$profile_user_id')");
}}}
```

Please help me,im new to php and this annoys me, i've been stuck on this since yesterday evening trying to figure it out.I really dont see whats the problem.How do i change my code?Everything works perfectly expect that friend_request() function part.

Answer (score 0):

in your form `username` input is missing, Based on the `username` value you have allowed into the block  `if (isset($_GET['username']) === true and empty($_GET['username']) === false) {`

```
    <form action="">
         <input type="text" name="username" value="your value">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send friend request!">
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you,but that is just a friend request button,it doesnt require text type.Username that i allowed in that blocked is for other purposes.

Comment: As your code need username is required, You can pass the username as hidden value like `<input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $username;?>">`

Comment: Still just refreshes the page add's into URL: username?username=username&submit=Send+friend+request%21

Comment: Am not sure, I have understand your comment!